# What is the method syntax for this LINQ, is it a join, and if not then what is it?

Tags: linq

I find myself using this pattern lots in LINQ:

```
    class Thing
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int ColorID { get; set; }
    }
    class Color
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
    static void Main()
    {
        var things = new List<Thing> { new Thing { ID = 1, ColorID = 1 }, new Thing { ID = 2, ColorID = 1 }, new Thing { ID = 3, ColorID = 2 }, new Thing { ID = 4, ColorID = 1 } };
        var colors = new List<Color> { new Color { ID = 1, Description = "red" }, new Color { ID = 2, Description = "green" }, new Color { ID = 3, Description = "blue" } };
        var joined = (from thing in things
                      from color in colors
                      where thing.ColorID == color.ID
                      select new { ID = thing.ID, Color = color.Description }).ToArray();
        foreach (var thing in joined)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("(" + thing.ID + ", " + thing.Color + ")");
        }
        //Writes:
        //(1, red)
        //(2, red)
        //(3, green
        //(4, red)
    }
```

The core of it, the four lines of query syntax, feel very much like an `INNER JOIN` that I might write in tSQL but when I look at [examples of LINQ query syntax for joins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx) they use the word `join`, while the above LINQ does not.

What is the 'join' that the above LINQ is performing and how would I rewrite it in LINQ method syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not performing a join at all, in terms of LINQ understanding. It's just filtering based on two properties where one *happens* to come from one range variable and the other *happens* to come from the other. In method syntax you'd write this as:

```
var joined = things.SelectMany(thing => colors,
                               (thing, color) => new { thing, color })
                   .Where(pair => pair.thing.ColorID == pair.color.ID)
                   .Select(pair => new { ID = pair.thing.ID,
                                         Color = pair.color.Description })
                   .ToArray();
```

The `pair` here is effectively automatically introduced by the compiler as a *transparent identifier*. This isn't due to the filtering in the `where`, but due to having multiple `from` clauses... every `from` clause after the first one uses `SelectMany`, and introduces a transparent identifier to allow you to refer to multiple range variables (`thing` and `color`) which are composed into a separate object so that each stage of the pipeline only notionally deals with one value.

Note that when you've got two `from` clauses:

```
from person in people
from book in books
```

... that *acts* like a Cartesian join... but LINQ allows for something more subtle, such as:

```
from person in people
from book in person.Books
```

In other words, the second sequence can depend on the "current" value from the first sequence. Any subsequent stage of the pipeline (e.g. a `where` or `select`) acts on each pair: one from the first sequence, and then one from the second sequence generated from the element in the first sequence.

Comment: Thanks John. I started LINQ by exclusively writing query syntax but recently I've been swapping to method syntax as it is often clearer  and more C#-like, but in this case it is much less straightforward though it does help explain what's going on.

Comment: I was about to answer that it performs an inner loop join. The syntax is very much how one wrote inner joins in SQL-89. But you say it is not.

Comment: @Magnus: It may be *translated* into an "inner loop join" by LINQ to SQL, of course...

Comment: @JonSkeet But this is linq to objects. But couldn't one say that a loop join is performed here. Compared to an hash join when using the actual `join` syntax?

Comment: @Magnus: You'd need to define "loop join" first... which sounds SQL-based to me. I think it's simpler just to define what it does. I've added some explanation to the end of the answer.

Comment: @dumbledad: It's definitely worth being familiar with both styles. Personally I tend to use the method syntax unless there are transparent identifiers involved - at which point query expressions end up being simpler.

Comment: @Magnus: Right - that *doesn't* cover the general LINQ to Objects case, as you don't start out with two sets - you start out with one sequence, and a function to produce a second sequence from each element of the first sequence. The case where the second sequence doesn't actually depend on the element in the first sequence is a special case.